# Avoid command-line password insecurity running MySQL from a script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have a bash script that logs into MySQL and creates a database.  It has a sequence that requests the MySQL credentials (username and password) and then executes

```
read username
read password
read databasename
mysql -u$username -p$password -e "CREATE DATABASE $databasename;"
```

whenever I run this script, I get the warning "Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure"

What is the right, secure way to create a script like this where you need to log into MySQL and then run a command?

Comment: On modern Linux kernels, passing content through the environment is safer than the command line. (All accounts on the system, even untrusted ones like `nobody`, can read command lines; only the same account and root can read environment variables).

Comment: BTW, always quote: `-u"$username" -p"$password"`; otherwise, an account with a password having spaces in it (or characters in the current value of `IFS`) is liable to misbehave. For similar reasons, it's better to use `IFS= read -r password`, so leading and trailing spaces and backslashes aren't discarded.

Comment: (The environment-variable approach involves setting `MYSQL_PWD`; the documentation warns that this is insecure, but that's not the case when targeting modern Linux -- anyone who can read your environment variables can also read your credential files).

Answer (score 0):

You can store your login details using the `mysql_config_editor`:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=username --password=password
```

Then run your command line query like:

```
mysql --login-path=local -e "statement"
```

See this [tutorial](https://www.looklinux.com/mysql-warning-using-a-password-on-the-command-line-interface-can-be-insecure/). There's an alternative method writing the configuration file directly for older versions of mySQL.

Comment: Does that not bring the same problem then specifying the password in the MySQL command? `ps aux` would list the password of `mysql_config_editor` too meaning someone who would watch processes could gather it, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you type `ps aux`, you can see every program currently executing on the computer, including the command line arguments. So... saying that "Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure" is a *massive* understatement.

See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html) for other options. Specifically, make a credentials file, ensure it is only readable by you, then fill it with your authentication details.

Comment: In other words, `chmod 600 password_file`. You'll also want to exit all terminals (to save the shell history), then enter a new terminal and delete all references to your password from ~/.bash_history.

Comment: He explicitly ask for *right way* not some NON script specific recommandations from the MySQL-docs. That is NOT an answer and the `ps aux` info is extra knowledge that SHOULD have been a comment.